# Transforming tree recursively in JS/ES6

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, tree

I am currently trying to transform a tree, given by in this form:

```
{"Parent": 
    {
    "Child1": ["toy1"],
    "Child2": 
          {
              "Nephew": ["toy2", "toy3"]
          }
    }
}
```

into a tree of the following form:

```
{
"name": "root",
"children": 
    [{"name":"Parent",
      "children": 
          [{
          "name":"Child1",
          "children": ["toy1"]
          },
          {
          "name":"Child2"
          "children": 
              [{
              "name":"Nephew",
              "children": ["toy2", "toy3"]
              }]
          }]
    }]
}
```

So basically I want to standardize the structure of the tree.
I tried that with the following code:

```
function recurse(elem) {
    if (typeof(elem) !== "object") return elem;
    level = [];
    for (let part in elem) {
        level.push({
            name: part,
            children: recurse(elem[part])
        });
        console.log(level);
    }
    return level;
}
restrucTree = {
    name: "root",
    children: recurse(tree)
};
```

But that apparently there are some errors concerning the correct recursion and building of the object since the root node (in this case "Parent") isn't included in the transformed tree. Furthermore this method fails if the tree branches in several sub-trees. In this case just the last one gets recognized.
My best guess is that ,while popping the stack of the recursion, stored objects get lost, but somehow I can't translate that to a solution.
If you have any idea, where this error comes from, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and iterate all keys and build new objects and take either the array or take the object for the next recursive call.

```js
function getParts(object) {
    return Array.isArray(object)
        ? object
        : Object.keys(object).map(function (k) {
            return { name: k, children: getParts(object[k]) };
        });
}

var data = { Parent: { Child1: ["toy1"], Child2: { Nephew: ["toy2", "toy3"] } } },
    result = { name: 'root', children: getParts(data) };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow, that works like a charm! Thanks a lot for the quick help. Did you see by any chance where my mistake in my code was?

Comment: you check for object, but arrays are objects, too. so you need a check for array.

Comment: Hmm, that's true, but the leaf part of the traversal was actually fine. Rather having multiple branches at once seemed to delete all previously collected information from other sibling-subtrees. Thanks nevertheless, maybe I'll figure it out by myself.